# How to intercept tilting in Android?

Tags: android, intercept, tilt

I would like to write a program using tilting functionality in android.

Is there any way to intercept it? What do I get back? a vector indicating the direction of the tilt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing to get your head around it the concept of a listener.
In Android there isn't a method called `getXtilt()`, `getYtilt()` etc to get the orientation.
Instead you need to create a **listener** which you register with the system.

Look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html).

See the `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` method? The Android system will invoke that method every time the sensor changes (which is very frequently).  In this case it will be the `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` sensor readings you will be receiving.

So when you get the SensorEvent ['event'](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) have a look at the `event.values[]` array. It will contain the sensor readings. In the example code in the Android doc they register the `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`. You should register the 
`Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`.  Have a look at the [values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) array for 
`Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION`. They are the tilt values you are looking for.

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you would have to use the Accelerometer and interpret the values and then make a decision based on them. Look up SensorEventListener and it should get you in the right direction.